# What should I do to merge my two accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

Accidentally, I now have two accounts for english.stackexchange.com, this one and [an unregistered one](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15987/guestlearner). Is it possible to merge the two accounts into either one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two accounts have been merged.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.